# Finding rows based on Conflicting conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, conditional-statements, conflict

i have a table filled with mails messages that contains all mails from certain domains. columns are - `domain_name, subject and receipt`.
i want to find all the domains in my database that have sent a 'welcome' mail and a receipt through out time.

in order for a mail to be a receipt :

```
g.receipt != '{}'
```

in order for a mail to be a 'Welcome' mail:

```
g.subject regexp 'Welcome'
```

the problem is that the two conditions create a conflict. i can't search for both of them because i will have 0 results. a single mail can be a Welcome **OR** Receipt.
but i need to find domains who sent both through out time.

all i could do is narrowing the possibilities with this:

```
   select 
    *
from
    (select 
        if(g.receipt != '{}', @R:=1, @R:=0) As Receipt,
            if(g.subject regexp 'Welcome', @M:=1, @M:=0) AS Welcome,
            g.domain_name,
            g.subject,
            g.receipt
    from
        table as g
         ) as B
where
 (@M:= 1 and @R:=0) or (@R:=1 and @M:=0)
group by domain_name, Welcome, Receipt
```

This code gives me all domains that sent a 'Welcome' Or a receipt. (i have other type of messages in the database). is there any way to code this so i wont need to find them with my eyes?

Thank you, i use mysql.

Comment: Have you tried self joining the table twice - one time for the first condition and one time for the second condition. After that group by domain and find the groups with not null condition from the both joins? Can't give concrete example cuz I'm writing from the phone.. ;)

Comment: i'm not at work right now but it sounds super interesting so i will try it tommorrow. can you write a concrete example plz? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the results you need. Note that I've called your table `domains` due to `table` being a reserved keyword.

```
select distinct domain_name from domains welcome_messages
where
    subject like '%Welcome%'
    and exists
    (
        select * from domains receipts
        where 
            receipts.receipt != '{}'
            and welcome_messages.domain_name = receipts.domain_name
    )
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df70a2/5) of the script above.